# Is it a good idea to use attention in VAEs for image generation?

Tags: deep-learning, generative-models, attention-mechanism, vae

There are research papers and codebases on GitHub that deal with VAEs for image generation on popular datasets like CelebA, etc. While surfing through Google Scholar I found self-attention and other attention mechanisms improve performance of GANs, but no proper equivalent papers in case of VAEs. Is there any particular reason why? Could it be related to the fact that sampling is in any case done from a normal distribution? Or is it just because research hasn't gone that far?

I found some papers that do use attention in VAEs but their objectives are very different, they deal with scene segmentation, image repainting, etc. but nothing that relates to generation capabilities. Nor did I find any articles against the use of it.

Finally, if there's no issue in mixing the two, which part of the VAE should be best suited for using attention.

Comment: I think that by the time self-attention became a big thing, that research on VAEs already died out a little bit. There might be some out there, but i havent seen any. There are 'more promising' techniques for image generation that have received the bulk of research attention. I see no problem with using transformers in a VAE. Quick google search and i saw some things regarding ViT-VAE. So i guess there is some stuff out there.